# Azure OS maximum disk size?

Tags: azure

According to [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-introduces-new-disks-sizes-up-to-4tb/), Azure now supports a maximum of 4095GB for a given OS disk.

I decided I'd take advantage of this for my new Postgresql DB which is going to be massive.

When I went to the portal to change the size of the OS disk, I noticed something odd:

[image]

**Questions**

1. Why does it tell me that "Azure supports OS disks up to 2 TB", yet it allowed me to enter 4TB?
2. If the OS does not recognize more than 2TB, I won't be able to use that space... Will I still be charged for it? Can Azure not check the OS and limit the size according to the OS limits?

Answer (score -1):

There's a difference between OS disk and Data disk. OS disk is the root on Linux or the C drive in Windows and should be used for OS only.
You should configure your PostgreSQL to use a data disk, which can be 4TB in size (or more if using disk striping).